# compare between drop-down option and validate

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement

There is condition on click of Submit button,
 If the Selected value is below 7 then Filling that Input comment box is mandatory. I am stuck with confusion, how to do it in very short way.

**HTML**

```
<form class="oiv-form" id="SurveyForm"  data-abide novalidate>
<select id="q1" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
    <option value="0/0">NA</option>
    <option value="1/10">1</option>
    <option value="2/10">2</option>
    <option value="3/10">3</option>
    <option value="4/10">4</option>
    <option value="5/10">5</option>
    <option value="6/10">6</option>
    <option value="7/10">7</option>
    <option value="8/10">8</option>
    <option value="9/10">9</option>
    <option value="10/10">10</option>
</select>
<span class="form-error">
    Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.
</span>
<div class="medium-3 large-4 column">
     <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder=" ">
     <span class="form-error">
         Yo, Please mention comments, why rating is below 7.
     </span>
</div>
 <button class="btn orange" type="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think u should see this link and implement in your code: [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/9uHgB/)

Comment: @MdAman thanks but i need to validated if the value is below 7/10. So, i am confused

Comment: Could you please post your `form` too? Where's the `submit` button? What have you tried till now?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have tired with creating multiple variable for every option, so it's long and i removed it.. now searching better way. let me add a submit button this

Comment: I would stop default form submission and check the value selected, after would submit if requirement is met or display the error message. Are you using jquery in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `selected text` from option and check it against the desired value. Below is the sample snippet.

```js
$('.orange').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var selectedVal=$("#q1 option:selected").text();
  if(selectedVal=="Select Value") //If nothing is selected
    return $("#q1").next().show();
  
  //if value is less than or equal to 7 or value = NA and textbox value is empty
  if((selectedVal=="NA" || parseInt(selectedVal) <=7) && $("#right-label").val().trim()=="")
    return $("#right-label").next().show(); 
  else //submit the form
    alert('form can be submitted');
    
});
```

```css
.form-error{
  color:red;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="oiv-form" id="SurveyForm"  data-abide novalidate>
<select id="q1" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
    <option value="0/0">NA</option>
    <option value="1/10">1</option>
    <option value="2/10">2</option>
    <option value="3/10">3</option>
    <option value="4/10">4</option>
    <option value="5/10">5</option>
    <option value="6/10">6</option>
    <option value="7/10">7</option>
    <option value="8/10">8</option>
    <option value="9/10">9</option>
    <option value="10/10">10</option>
</select>
<span class="form-error">
    Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.
</span>
<div class="medium-3 large-4 column">
     <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder=" ">
     <span class="form-error">
         Yo, Please mention comments, why rating is below 7.
     </span>
</div>
 <button class="btn orange" type="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done done some changes and it's working. Now, i have to do it for multiple dropdown and comment boxs.

Comment: Then you can get array of `dropdowns` loop with $.each and write the logic within `$.each` or you can make use of `for` loop..

Comment: I will try first, as i am still getting with jquery. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="">
    <select id="q1" required="required" onchange="checkValue(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Value</option>
        <option value="0/0">NA</option>
        <option value="1/10">1</option>
        <option value="2/10">2</option>
        <option value="3/10">3</option>
        <option value="4/10">4</option>
        <option value="5/10">5</option>
        <option value="6/10">6</option>
        <option value="7/10">7</option>
        <option value="8/10">8</option>
        <option value="9/10">9</option>
        <option value="10/10">10</option>
    </select>
    <span class="form-error">Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.</span>
    <div class="medium-3 large-4 column">
        <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder=" ">
        <span class="form-error">Yo, Please mention comments, why rating is below 7.</span>
        <input type="submit">
</form>

//right-label is text box id
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValue(val)
    {
        if(val)
        {
            val = val.split("/");
            if (val[0] < 7)
            {
                $("#right-label").prop('required',true);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#right-label").prop('required',false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#right-label").prop('required',true);
        }
    }
</script>
```